# Multiple Custom Taxonomy Rewrite

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules, slug

I have registered two custom taxonomies of 'location' and 'type' registered before my post type of 'chalet' and have the rewrite rules set to

```
'slug' => 'chalets/%location%'
'slug' => 'chalets/%type%'
'slug' => 'chalets'
```

respectively. The URL structure for archives that I need is:

.../chalets/

.../chalets/[location term] eg /chalets/val-thorens

.../chalets/[type term] eg /chalets/ski-chalet

This works to a point but the second rule (whichever taxonomy is registered second) overrides the first and so the first subsequently returns a 404. How can I have both rewrites work or am I asking for the moon on a stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use separate base for both custom taxonomies.
For example:

default URL:
/chalets/

location term URL:
/chalets/location/%location%

type term URL:
/chalets/type/%type%

Rewrite rules need to identify the requested custom taxonomy via URL. So, a base URL identifier is required in your case.

Comment: Thanks, @Rayat. I've got it working without the base for 'type' but I guess having both without the base was too big of an ask. Turns out the client is happy to keep the /location/ base so it's all good.

Comment: That's great news! You're welcome.